# Blackjack game not functioning on second restart

Tags: python, function, game-development, blackjack, replit

```
############### Our Blackjack House Rules #####################

## The deck is unlimited in size. 
## There are no jokers. 
## The Jack/Queen/King all count as 10.
## The the Ace can count as 11 or 1.
## Use the following list as the deck of cards:
## cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
## The cards in the list have equal probability of being drawn.
## Cards are not removed from the deck as they are drawn.
## The computer is the dealer.

from replit import clear
from art import logo
import random

cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]




computers_first_card = random.choice(cards)


# print(score)

# print(initial_hand)

def play_again():
  play_again = input("Play again? y or n: ")
  if play_again == "n":
    return False
  else:
    clear()
    blackjack_game()

def ace_check(hand, score):
  if 11 in hand and score > 21:
    hand[11] = 1
    score - 10

def blackjack_game():
  print(logo)

  playing_game = True



  initial_hand = [random.choice(cards), random.choice(cards)]

  score = sum(initial_hand)

  computers_score = computers_first_card

  computers_hand = [computers_first_card]

  while playing_game:
    print(f"Your cards: {initial_hand}, current score: {score}")
    print(f"Computer's first card: {computers_first_card}")
    draw_again = input("Type 'y' to get another card, type 'n' to pass: ")
  
    if draw_again == 'y':
      draw = random.choice(cards)
      ace_check(initial_hand, score)
      if draw + score > 21:
          initial_hand.append(draw)
          score += sum(initial_hand) - score
          print(f"Your final hand: {initial_hand}, final score: {score}")
          print(f"Computer's final hand: {computers_first_card}")
          print("You Lose!")
          if play_again() == False:
            playing_game = False
          else:
            play_again()
      else:  
        initial_hand.append(draw)
        score += sum(initial_hand) - score
    else:
      while computers_score < score:
        draw = random.choice(cards)
        ace_check(computers_hand, computers_score)
        if draw + computers_score > 21:
          print(f"Your final hand: {initial_hand}, final score: {score}")
          print(f"Computer's final hand: {computers_hand}, final score: {computers_score}")
          print("Computer went over 21 on draw!")
          print("You Win!")
          if play_again() == False:
            playing_game = False
          else:
            play_again()

        else:
          computers_hand.append(draw)
          computers_score = sum(computers_hand)
      if computers_score > score:
        print(f"Your final hand: {initial_hand}, final score: {score}")
        print(f"Computer's final hand: {computers_hand}, final score: {computers_score}")
        print("You Lose!")
        if play_again() == False:
          playing_game = False
        else:
          play_again()
        
    

play_game = input("Do you want to play a game of Blackjack? Type 'y' or 'n': ")

if play_game == "y":
  clear()
  blackjack_game()
```

In the above code, on replit, if I go over 21 after restarting an initial game when prompted, and inputing 'n' to end the program, the input print from:

```
def play_again():
  play_again = input("Play again? y or n: ")
  if play_again == "n":
    return False
  else:
    clear()
    blackjack_game()
```

Gets printed twice and breaks my program.

The first game always works properly. I can properly input 'n' to stop the program, but once I input I'd like to play another game, when endgame arrives again and I try to stop with inputing 'n' into play_again(), I get asked the same input twice.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Here's my replit of the program so far below:

https://replit.com/@AbrahamFrancis1/blackjack-start#main.py

Comment: Why are you calling `blackjack_game()` recursively? And why do you execute `play_again()` again after the user inputted "y"? Every time you call `play_again()`, there's an `else` that calls it again if the first call doesn't return `False`. But also, if the user chooses anything that's not "n", it will call `blackjack_game()`, before the execution of `blackjack_game()` ends. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: If you want to break the while loop, use `break`. Setting the condition of the loop to `False` isn't going to break it before that particular loop finishes, it's just that the next iteration is not going to happen.

Comment: A [mre] is surely going to help both us and you to debug it.

Comment: What does it means "breaks my program"? Do you get an error message?